# How does the lazy 'take' function compute the Scala stream further?

Tags: scala, scala-streams

In Martin Odersky’s book “Programming in Scala” there is an example of computing the Fibonacci sequence starting with 2 numbers passed as arguments to the function fibFrom.

```
def fibFrom(a: Int, b: Int): Stream[Int] =
       a #:: fibFrom(b, a + b)
```

If you apply the method take() to this recursive function like:

```
fibFrom(1, 1).take(15).print
```

The output will be:

```
1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, empty
```

Maybe this output is obvious for more experienced people, but I don’t understand how exactly this method take() makes the stream to be calculated further. Is 15 somehow nonobviously passed into fibFrom()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
a #:: fibFrom(b, a + b)
```

you created Stream object, and that object has head which is Int and tail which is function. Take is function of Stream that will calculate 15 elements using tail and head. You can check source code of take() function:

```
  override def take(n: Int): Stream[A] = (
    // Note that the n == 1 condition appears redundant but is not.
    // It prevents "tail" from being referenced (and its head being evaluated)
    // when obtaining the last element of the result. Such are the challenges
    // of working with a lazy-but-not-really sequence.
    if (n <= 0 || isEmpty) Stream.empty
    else if (n == 1) cons(head, Stream.empty)
    else cons(head, tail take n-1)
  )
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the thing that should be pointed is that **`Stream` is lazily evaluated**:

> The class Stream implements lazy lists where elements are only
>   evaluated when they are needed.

Quoted from [scala-lang.org](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.html)

`fibFrom` function is returning a `Stream`, so we understand that the function won't do nothing, even when called; it will start calculating the numbers only when you try to access the `Stream`.
`take` function also returns a `Stream` and acts lazily.
The `print` function is the one that actually calls the recursion and stops when filling the output with 15 numbers (like your example).

You can easily check this by performing the functions one by one and see the output.
Lets run only `fibFrom`:
[image]
We can see that the returned value is a `Stream` and the numbers are not calculated yet.

Now, lets see what `take(15)` does:
[image]
Same as our first test.

Eventually, performing `print` is giving us the desired result thus actually running `fibFrom` recursively until reaching 15 numbers:
[image]

**Bonus:** Converting the Stream to any non lazy data structure will trigger the computations:
[image]